PowerApps filter Excel data table
My goal is to have a user input a number in the textinput1 input and select a state from the dropdown1 and hit submit, once they hit submit it filters an excel data table. So if they put 1 in the textinput1, itll filter the New Center column to 1 and if they select Texas from the dropdown1, it filters the Location column to Texas.
On the data table items property I have the following formula
Filter(Table1,StartsWith('New Center',textinput1.text) && Location = dropdown1.selected.value)
I'm not seeing any errors or issue, but its not filtering the table. Just shows "Nothing to display"

In your filter condition your are checking if both conditions are present, you just need to add a condition in OR, which will check if the filter value is not selected or is blank then ignore this filter. Follow is an example how you can add it:
Filter(Table1,
       And( 
           IsBlank(textinput1.Text) || StartsWith('New Center',textinput1.Text),
           IsBlank(dropdown1.selected.Value) || Location = dropdown1.selected.Value
      )
)


Sadly, This didn’t work. Same results. The PowerApp requires both fields to be filled in before proceeding, so there should not be blanks anyways.

I connected the text input and location drop down to the same data source. That helped

Did my answer worked for you?
